How to get dynamic value from Json file generated during execution and use it in next command for Jenkins pipeline?
I have a Script which is generating a Dynamic session_id in a json file and after execution of script I want to use that session_id in next command like for example below is JSON file

   "name": "TestName",
   "session_id": "51a2ce15-2caf-47e8-9415-405d623b4fb3"
   
}

I want to save it in a variable SessionID(or any other name) and then want to use in a command like below
npm run test --session_id %SessionID%

I have found a tool Jq which is used to play with JSON file, I installed it on my windows server.
And then in Jenkins step I'm trying to execute batch script for jq
steps {
                script {
                     bat "jq .session_id sessionFile.json > out.tmp"
                     bat "set /p SessionID=<out.tmp"
                     echo "%SessionID%"
                     bat "npm run test --session_id %SessionID%"
                }
            }

But getting jq is not recognised error in jenkins console log.
Then I tried  manually to login on server and Executed command
jq .session_id sessionFile.json > out.tmp
It's working fine as ADMIN user
C:/USERS/AUT >>  jq .session_id sessionFile.json > out.tmp

but for Jenkins as its running as C:\ProgramData\Jenkins\.jenkins\workspace\OrderCreation
So Tried command
C:\ProgramData\Jenkins\.jenkins\workspace\OrderCreation> jq .session_id sessionFile.json > out.tmp

It's returning 'Access is Denied' reponse.
Can anyone please guide how to resolve the issue? OR s there any other alternative solution to handle this Problem?

You have an issue with 'jq' working in your Jenkins pipeline. the error message "jq is not recognized".
Here you can try,
Add the path to 'jq' executable to the system's PATH environment.
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Path\To\JqExecutable

Replace 'C:\Path\To\JqExecutable' with the actual path where 'jq' is installed.
